# VBA Page Number in Word within text string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have never used a question board like this before, so I apologize if I get this wrong ..

I have a word document that I need to insert "Page X of Y" with VBA ...but I need to insert it into a string of text. The catch is I need it to be a field, so that it updates if they add more pages to the document

My header looks like this

[image]

```
For j = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(j)
       .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = strfirstline & Chr(9) & "Section " & strfileLeft & Chr(13) _
       & strsecondline & Chr(9) & "Page " & "WHAT DO I PUT HERE" & " of " & "WHAT DO I PUT HERE" & Chr(13) _
       & strthirdline & Chr(9) & strthirddate & Chr(13) _
    & strfourthline & Chr(9) & "Issued for " & strissuedfor & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Count).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select
        With Selection
            .TypeText Text:="Page "
            .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE ", PreserveFormatting:=True
            .TypeText Text:=" of "
            .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES ", PreserveFormatting:=True
        End With
```

Lines 4 and 6 are inserting the values for you.

You could also try plugging in `{ PAGE }` and `{NUMPAGES}` to see if that works. PAGE is the current page; NUMPAGES is the total in the document.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! So the VBA definitely works to give me the X of Y ... but I need the result to then show up in my string ... I tried to find a way that I could make it "PageNumber =" and then the VBA so I could insert "PageNumber" into the VBA that I supplied, but couldn't get it to work. I tried inserting { PAGE } and {NUMPAGES} into my VBA but got an error

Comment: @TLS You can't make it part of your string. The field codes must be inserted separately. Just put your string "parts" where `.TypeText` is in the suggestion. There's no way to make them part of the string so that the field codes are inserted into the Header. If you don't insert field codes, the page information won't dynamically update. It is possible to insert some kind of placeholder into your string, write that to the document, then use code *after the fact* to Find the placeholder and replace it with a field code, but that would make no sense if you're using VBA anyway...

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Your comment helped me get it to work. I was looking at it all backwards. Once I moved my string into the page numbering formula, it was perfect!